# jQuery continue loop when ajax ends

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, loops, for-loop

I have a loop and I want it to run when ajax ends everytime in the loop.
Is that possible?

> > for (var i=1;i<20;i++){
> >       if (keepruning = 1) {
> >     keepruning = 0;
> >
> > $.post( "getname.php", { id: myarr[i] } )
> >                   .done(function( data ) {
> >                     keepruning = 1
> >                   });
> >
> > }

This is as close as I got... and this doesn't work.
Any help would be very much appriciated;

Comment: The **a** in ajax stands for **asynchronous**. This means it's non-blocking and so the loop will complete before the first request finishes.

Comment: you want the loop to continue running from the point it stopped ? you want the loop to just run or what ?

Comment: from the point it stopped. Like a "wait" function.

Comment: you'll need to set up break/ return offsets or use a Sync ajax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery `ajax` is `{async:true}` by default so request dose previous request response
you should use `$.ajax({...})` instead of `$.post` so you can add  `{async:false}` in parameters 
Like

```
$.ajax({
   url : "xyz.php", 
   async : false,
   dataType : json
   success : function(data){
           //code here
   }
});
```

You can also add `{async:false}` globally.

**NOTE**: This will work with all ajax function that define on page

```
$.ajaxSetup({async:false});
```

Comment: Just a note that [it's extremely poor practice to set async false](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call/14220323#14220323)

Answer (score 1):

To do it the way you are trying to do you need a recursive function, because by default $.post is async.

```
(function proceed(i) {
    $.post('getname.php', {id: myarr[i]}).done(function(data) {
        if (++i < 20) proceed(i);
    });
}(0));
```

But you should think before doing that. Wouldn't simple parallel requests solve the problem?

You could also make sync requests, but I don't recommend that.

Comment: You don't recommend async requests? How would you make parallel requests not in async

Comment: Also you want `i++ < 20` to be consistent with op

Comment: sync requests, my friend.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i=1;i<20;i++){
if (keepruning = 1) {
    keepruning = 0;

    $.ajax({
        url: "getname.php",
        type: "post",
        async: false,
        data:{ id: myarr[i] },
        success: function (data) {
            keepruning = 1;
        },
        error : function (data) {
            keepruning = 0;
        }
    });
}
```

}

This is one way, with sync ajax

Answer (score 0):

Using `async : false` freeze the browser, which is UX wise not a good solution. If it a prlbem for you, you can also use a self-calling function to do the loop :

```
loop(0)
function loop(i){
    $.post( "getname.php", { id: myarr[i] } ) .done(function(){
       if(i < 20) loop(i++)
    });
}
```